# Find the largest number in an array of alphanumeric string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation, sorting

I have a array with data like below

```
 var arr = [Daaguva1, Dagguva2, Dagguva3, Dagguva4, Daggu5, Dag6, Dagguv7, Dagg8, Daggs9, Dagguvati10];
```

I want to get the highest number in this array of string i.e. 10 .
I need this number so that I can auto increment the number to 11 . Any help?

Comment: seems invalid array.

Comment: array should be as follows: var arr = ['Daaguva1', 'Dagguva2', 'Dagguva3', 'Dagguva4', 'Daggu5', 'Dag6', 'Dagguv7', 'Dagg8', 'Daggs9', 'Dagguvati10'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all names match the same structure (letters followed by the target number) - then use a regex to strip out all non-digit characters and parseInt the remaining portion to yield a number. Set a high score and iterate through the array and compare the stripped down numbers to the high value and if it is higher - set the higest value to that.

```js
  var arr = ['Daaguva1', 'Dagguva2', 'Dagguva3', 'Dagguva4', 'Daggu5', 'Dag6', 'Dagguv7', 'Dagg8', 'Daggs9', 'Dagguvati10'];
  
  var high=0;
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var num = parseInt(arr[i].replace(/\D+/g, ''));
    if(num > high){high = num};
    } 
  console.log('highest number is: ' + high);
  
  var nextNum = high +=1;
  console.log('next number will be: '+ nextNum )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a saviour :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
var arr = ['Daaguva1', 'Dagguva2', 'Dagguva3', 'Dagguva4', 'Daggu5', 'Dag6', 'Dagguv7', 'Dagg8', 'Daggs9', 'Dagguvati10'];

// iterate over the array
var num = arr.reduce(function(g, str) {
  // get the number from string and parse it
  var num = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10) || 0;
  // return the greater value
  return g < num ? num : g;
  // set the initial value as lowest value 
  // either negative infinity or 0 as your requirement
}, -Infinity);

console.log(num);
```

Comment: @ArpitaDutta :  glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMaxValuefromArray() {
     var maxNum = parseInt(arr[0].replace( /^\D+/g, ''), 10),
         tempNum;

     for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          tempNum = parseInt(arr[i].replace( /^\D+/g, ''), 10);
          if (tempNum > maxNum) {
                   maxNum = tempNum;
          }
     }
     return maxNum;
```

}

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/881juLr9/

Comment: Thanks.. It worked liked charm. But I can mark only one as answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regEx = /\d+/;
var arr = ["Daaguva1", "Dagguva2", "Dagguva3", "Dagguva4", "Daggu5", "Dag6", "Dagguv7", "Dagg8", "Dagguvati10"];

var bigestIndex=0;
arr.map(function(data){
 var numIndex=data.match(regEx).index;
 if(numIndex>bigestIndex)
 bigestIndex=numIndex;
});

console.log('bigestIndex',bigestIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple it is.

```
var arr = ['Daaguva1', 'Dagguva2', 'Dagguva3', 'Dagguva4', 'Daggu5', 'Dag6', 'Dagguv7', 'Dagg8', 'Daggs9', 'Dagguvati10'];
var r = /\d+/; // this is regex to detect digits
var max = 0;
for(var i= 0 ; i<arr.length;i++){ // iterate over the array
    if(max < parseInt(arr[i].match(r)[0])){ // match it and if larger number found then assign it to `max`
        max = arr[i].match(r)[0];
    }
}
console.log(max);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejhp4Lay/)